# from unix timestamp to datetime

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I have something like `/Date(1370001284000+0200)/` as timestamp. I guess it is a unix date, isn't it? How can I convert this to a date like this: `31.05.2013 13:54:44`

I tried [THIS](http://www.epochconverter.com/) converter for 1370001284 and it gives the right date. So it is in seconds.

But I still get the wrong date for:

```
var substring = unix_timestamp.replace("/Date(", "");
substring = substring.replace("000+0200)/", "");
var date = new Date();
date.setSeconds(substring);
return date;
```

Comment: Did your code generate the timestamp value, or is it outside of your control? I ask because `1370001284000+0200` is not a valid timestamp because it looks like miliseconds, not seconds, and contains zone information.

Comment: Out of my control. Because of that I am not really sure what it is. But I know that 1370001284000+0200 and 31.05.2013 13:54:44 matches.

Comment: Assuming you've got your substring as "1370001284000" (the time in milliseconds from the epoch) you could just do `var date = new Date( parseInt( substring, 10 ) );`

Comment: The best answer without using momentjs https://stackoverflow.com/a/25166955/1536309

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Note my use of `t.format` comes from using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), it is not part of JavaScript's standard `Date` prototype.

A Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

The presence of the `+0200` means the numeric string is not a Unix timestamp as it contains timezone adjustment information. You need to handle that separately.

If your timestamp string is in milliseconds, then you can use the milliseconds constructor and [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to format the date into a string:

```
var t = new Date( 1370001284000 );
var formatted = moment(t).format("dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM:ss");
```

If your timestamp string is in seconds, then use `setSeconds`:

```
var t = new Date();
t.setSeconds( 1370001284 );
var formatted = moment(t).format("dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM:ss");
```

Comment: For seconds the year is somethign like 2056. So it has to be miliseconds. I tried var date = new Date(1370001284000); but it says invalid date. Edit: I think the timestamp is a bit weird, because if I do something like timestamp * 100, I get a valid date but for the year 4500 or so.

Comment: You need to strip the `+0200` part from the string, convert to a number, then supply it as an argument to the `Date( miliseconds )` constructor.

Comment: @Dai `t.format is not a function` does it require [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: @mu3 I was quoting from the OP who seems to be using Moment.js as you pointed out.

Comment: My timestamp is in UTC format. Any change I need to make here for that? How can I have am/pm?

Comment: Second example doesn't work, as it adds the number of seconds to the current date, which is near year 2065.

Comment: yes, you can convert unix timestamp to date using  Moment js, here is complete tutorial for this https://coderszine.com/convert-timestamp-to-date-using-javascript/.  You can also convert it using online tools http://epochconvert.com

Answer (score 20):

Looks like you might want the ISO format so that you can retain the timezone.

```
var dateTime = new Date(1370001284000);
dateTime.toISOString(); // Returns "2013-05-31T11:54:44.000Z"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score 8):

Without moment.js:

```js
var time_to_show = 1509968436; // unix timestamp in seconds

var t = new Date(time_to_show * 1000);
var formatted = ('0' + t.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + t.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

document.write(formatted);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `/Date(ms + timezone)/` is a ASP.NET syntax for JSON dates. You might want to use a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/) for parsing such dates. It would come in handy if you need to manipulate or print the dates any time later.

Answer (score 3):

If using react:

```
import Moment from 'react-moment';
Moment.globalFormat = 'D MMM YYYY';
```

then:

```
<td><Moment unix>{1370001284}</Moment></td>
```

Comment: it is not working, getting the wrong output

Comment: in my case i tried with out unix on< Moment >{}</moment>

Answer (score 2):

Import moment js:

```
var fulldate = new Date(1370001284000);
var converted_date = moment(fulldate).format(");
```

Comment: You're adding an answer to a question which is three years old. It's generally best if you explain (in the answer) why you feel this answer is better than the existing answers. Otherwise it is likely to be downvoted or removed altogether.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using React I found [`'react-moment'`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment) library more easy to handle for Front-End related tasks, just import `<Moment>` component and add `unix` prop:

```
import Moment from 'react-moment'

 // get date variable
 const {date} = this.props 

 <Moment unix>{date}</Moment>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that Using the library **momentjs** in javascript you can have the whole data information in an object with:

```
const today = moment(1557697070824.94).toObject();
```

You should obtain an object with this properties:

```
today: {
  date: 15,
  hours: 2,
  milliseconds: 207,
  minutes: 31,
  months: 4
  seconds: 22,
  years: 2019
}
```

It is very useful when you have to calculate dates.

Comment: how do you convert the month to something like April instead of 4?

Answer (score 1):

for people as dumb as  myself, my date was in linux epoch
but it was a string instead of an integer, and that's why i was getting
**RangeError: Date value out of bounds**

so if you are getting the epoch from an api, parseInt it first

```
var dateTime = new Date(parseInt(1370001284000));
dateTime.toISOString();
```