# Parsing Datetime format passed from ajax to "dd/MM/yyyy"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

From the ajax, I am receiving datetime as:

[image: Screen Shot]

Not sure now to parse it with jquery to "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [from unix timestamp to datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978331/from-unix-timestamp-to-datetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you posted your question in the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tag, you could embed your approach in a `jQuery` function:

```
//returns a Date() object in dd/MM/yyyy
$.formattedDate = function(dateToFormat) {
    var dateObject = new Date(dateToFormat);
    var day = dateObject.getDate();
    var month = dateObject.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = dateObject.getFullYear();
    day = day < 10 ? "0" + day : day; 
    month = month < 10 ? "0" + month : month; 
    var formattedDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;    
    return formattedDate;
};

//usage:
var formattedDate = $.formattedDate(someDateObjectToFormat);
```

This will work with both valid `Date` objects and the result you get back from your JSON string:

```
var randomDate = new Date("2015-09-30");
var epochTime = new Date(1263183045000);
var jsonResult = "\/Date(1263183045000)\/";

//outputs "30/09/2015"
alert($.formattedDate(randomDate)); 
//both below output "11/01/2010"
alert($.formattedDate(epochTime)); 
alert($.formattedDate(new Date(parseInt(jsonResult.substr(6)))));
```

Aside: the format of the date portion in your result is in [Unix time](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/)—aka Epoch time—i.e. the number of seconds elapsed after 01/01/1970 00:00:00  UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Got Solved with following code

```
 var date = new Date(parseInt(data.UPDATED_ON.substr(6)));
 alert(date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
// convert MVC datetime (e.g. "\/Date(628318530718)\/") into JavaScript Date
value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
```