# How can convert datetime form Net to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Please don't make duplicate vs [ASP.NET Parse DateTime result from ajax call to javascript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314663/asp-net-parse-datetime-result-from-ajax-call-to-javascript-date) and [Parsing DateTime format passed from Ajax to “dd/MM/yyyy”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878023/parsing-datetime-format-passed-from-ajax-to-dd-mm-yyyy), I have been read carefully. But my question is differences.

I have data from asp.net load by ajax below.

```
 Datetime in c#: "2019-05-04" 

 The result in ajax is: "/Date(1556895600000+0900)/"
```

You can see the result automatic add time UTC offset to DateTime, I don't know why.

How can I convert to DateTime in javascript vs data above?

```js
var d = new Date(("/Date(1556895600000+0900)/").match(/\d+/)[0] * 1)
console.log(d)
```

You can see: Result "2019-05-03T15:00:00.000Z", But I expect result "2019-05-04".
How can I do this?

Comment: That's an invalid date value. Do you have access to the C# code?

Comment: Otherwise, you're going to need to add 9 hours to `d` to get the correct value.

Comment: @ Heretic Monkey: public DateTime TheDate { get; set; }, My sytem publish for Korea, and Vietnam, China, Japan. But in Korea add 9, Vietnam add 7...=> This is not good solution.

Comment: You can set up C# to output whatever date format you want, including ISO 8601 in UTC, which you can pass directly to `new Date()` without a lot of this parsing work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look I'm no dates expert but the following looks convincing to me

```js
const parse = str => {
    let [_, timestamp, offsetHours, offsetMinutes] = str.match(/(\d+)([+-]\d\d)(\d\d)/).map(Number);
    
    let date = new Date(timestamp);
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + offsetHours);
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + offsetMinutes);
    return date;
}

console.log(
    parse("/Date(1556895600000+0900)/")
    .toJSON()
)
console.log(
    parse("/Date(1556895600000-0700)/")
    .toJSON()
)
```

Here's a ES3 version in case it doesn't work in older browsers (as the OP said in the comments)

```js
function parse(str) {
    var matches = str.match(/(\d+)([+-]\d\d)(\d\d)/).map(Number);
    var timestamp = matches[1];
    var offsetHours = matches[2];
    var offsetMinutes = matches[3];
  
    var date = new Date(timestamp);
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + offsetHours);
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + offsetMinutes);
    return date;
}


console.log(
    parse("/Date(1556895600000+0900)/")
    .toJSON()
)
console.log(
    parse("/Date(1556895600000-0700)/")
    .toJSON()
)
```

Comment: Thank Devansh J. But it only work on Chrome. How can you fix it on IE?

Comment: Sorry again. How can work with timeofset <0 for example: /Date(1556895600000-0700)?