# Angular copy a unix date to an angular/js date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When the user clicks the button I want it to copy the vm.checkin (unix date) to the angular type=date field.

```
<input type="date" ng-model="vm.receiptForm.paidDate" id="receiptPaidDate">
<button ng-click="vm.receiptForm.paidDate = (vm.checkin * 1000) | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'">
    <span class="size-tiny">Copy Date</span>
</button>
```

Is that possible to do?  I cant seem to make it work.

Comment: What is vm.checkin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model for [`input[type=date]`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) must always be a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), but [`date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) formats `date` to a `string` based on the provided format. You just need to convert your timestamp to a date as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978331/from-unix-timestamp-to-datetime) and then assign it to `vm.receiptForm.paidDate`.

**UPDATE:** as an option you can create your [custom `filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) to achieve the desired functionality, see the code snippet below:

```js
var module = angular.module("demo", []);

module.filter('tsToDate', function () {
    return function (timestamp) {
        return new Date(timestamp);
    };
});

module.controller('Demo', [function Demo() {
    var vm = this; 
    vm.checkin = 1529442000000;  
    vm.receiptForm = {
        paidDate: ''
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="Demo as vm">   
    <div>
        <button ng-click="vm.receiptForm.paidDate = (vm.checkin | tsToDate)">Copy Date</button>
    </div>        
    <input type="date" ng-model="vm.receiptForm.paidDate" />    
    <code>
        {{ vm.receiptForm }}
    </code>  
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh so there is no way of doing it inside the html page?  You have to do it in the controller?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard yes, you can do it in controller. Or you can create a directive with [custom converters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) that will allow `input[type=date]` to work with unix timestamps, [something like this could work for you](http://jsfiddle.net/8jFpV/773/).

Comment: @torbenrudgaard also added an example using custom filter