# how to use Momentjs with react

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, livestamp.js

Hi i need to convert timestamp to something like Minutes/Hours/Days ago. I am using moment .But as these are j-query plugins so i am feeling challenges in executing that in react.

I have often heard that it is not recommended to use j-query with react.Or is there any other way to sort things out without using j-query

Comment: This question is beneficial for those who don't want to add j-query plugins in react.I have searched on the moment official documentation too but there was no clear example on how to use timestamp with moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `moment.js` in react.

1) Install moment.js package `npm install moment --save`

2) Import `moment` in your React component

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

Convert your timestamp (miliseconds) to date using `new Date(1567485137)` and use `fromNow` method of moment js.

```
moment(new Date(timestamp in milisecond).fromNow()
```

If you want to values as only days ago you can use `from` method

```
moment(new Date(timestamp in milisecond)).from(new Date())
```

Using **react-moment**

If you are using `react-moment` then use `Moment` component as below:

```
import Moment from "react-moment";
```

then use as below

```
<Moment fromNow date={new Date(timestamp in milisecond).toJSON()} />
```

Comment: import Moment from 'react-moment';
Am i importing the right thing ?

Comment: it is returning 50 years ago

Comment: 1567485137 is second or milisecond ?

Comment: it is in seconds.

Comment: what should be expected output?

Comment: Janed thankyou for helping but i am not getting the desired result.So let me clear you whole scenario. My timestamp is in seconds whose value is 1567557135 and you can check on https://www.epochconverter.com/ that it's relative 6 hours ago. I want to display that thing only. for lesser than hour it show seconds ago and then less than day it should show hours ago and then after days ago.This is the whole thing.

Comment: Obviously as your converting seconds to milliseconds 1567485137 * 100. you need to figure out time in milliseconds by your own. Give timestamp data as millisecond and it will work.

Comment: it is working fine for {moment(new Date(1567485137000 )).fromNow()} . I have converted seconds to miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your timestamp to `Date` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16978396/5198054) with Moment.Js. Since you do not have the timezone adjustment, you can simply convert it as shown below.

```
var t = new Date( 1370001284000 );
var formatted = t.format("dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM:ss");
```

After converting it  you can find the difference by `calculatedDate.FromNow()` method using Moment.Js.